# Use T9 dictionary from mobile phone for own chatapp

Tags: javascript, mobile

I'm writing a chatapplication using Rhomobile (Ruby). 
I'm using javascript to achieve this. Is there any possibility to activate the use of T9 dictionary that's already on the phone for a textarea (newmsg_body) to send messages?

```
     <div id="inner">
        <span id="inputspan"><input type="text" id="newmsg_body" /></span>
        <input type="button" value="Send" id="newmsg_sendbutton" onclick="sendMessage();" />
      </div>
```

Google Talk also uses this. I want the same functionality.

Thanks !